# How to prove a filter has linear phase response?

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I have designed an FIR filter to have linear phase response using odd-symmetry design. The coefficients of this filter are {2,1,3,1,0,-1,-3,-1,-2}. I am now being asked to prove it has linear phase response, I dont think saying odd symmetry design is deemed a sufficient answer. Please help

Comment: SO deals with programming related questions. Have a look  [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) for questions concerning dsp theory

Answer (score 0):

If you add the appropriate (negative) delay, so that the middle of the impulse response goes to t=0, then the phase response becomes constant.

This is easy to show, because an anti-symmetric function has no cosine components.

Since a delay is linear phase, adding back the opposite delay results in a linear phase total response.

Note that the definition of "linear" here is a little loose.  The phase response of an anti-symmetric filter is *not* a multiple of frequency.  It's a multiple of frequency plus a constant offset.  The function is still a line, and so we still call this "linear phase" in most cases.

The group delay of the filter is still constant, since group delay is the derivative of phase w.r.t frequency.